# How to set product special prices to 50% of regular price for a specific category and time span?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, catalog-price-rules, special-price, offers

Is there a simple way, maybe with the catalog price rules, to set the special price of all products of a specific category to 50% of the regular price and set a start and end date?

We have near to 2000 Products in a Category that we want to reduce to the prices by 50%, so editing these manually isn't an option.

I've tried the Catalog Pricing Rules, but I could not get this to work.

If it isn't possible by Price Rules, is this possible with an sql query or similar?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Catalog price rules is what you need to do this.

When you set up a catalog price rule you need to click the "Save and Apply" button either on the main catalog rule screen or as your making the rule otherwise it will be saved but not applied.